# How do you connect a geometry to two moving vertices

Tags: three.js

I have created some box geometries in my threejs app and I have successfully drawn a cylinder from the center of one to the center of another using the code below:

```
function cylinderMesh(pointX, pointY, material) {
    var direction = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(pointY, pointX);
    var orientation = new THREE.Matrix4();
    orientation.lookAt(pointX, pointY, new THREE.Object3D().up);
    orientation.multiply(new THREE.Matrix4(1, 0, 0, 0,
                                           0, 0, 1, 0,
                                           0, -1, 0, 0,
                                           0, 0, 0, 1));
    var edgeGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(2, 2, direction.length(), 8, 1);
    var edge = new THREE.Mesh(edgeGeometry, material);
    edge.applyMatrix(orientation);
    edge.position.x = (pointY.x + pointX.x) / 2;
    edge.position.y = (pointY.y + pointX.y) / 2;
    edge.position.z = (pointY.z + pointX.z) / 2;
    return edge;
}

scene.add(cylinderMesh(vertex1, vertex2, globalMaterial));
```

My question is:  How to I keep the cylinder "connected" to the two vertices I provide if they move?

I don't want to use a `THREE.Line` because I can't control the width of the line and I have noticed weird issues with clipping if the camera gets too close.

Any ideas?